# Windows Explorer freezes when I try to right-click, rename or move files in a mounted cloud drive (via rclone mount)

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, mount, freeze

I have already asked [this question in the rclone forum](https://forum.rclone.org/t/cannot-rename-or-move-files-in-an-rclone-mounted-remote-renaming-or-moving-folders-works-flawlessly/15787), but unfortunately we weren't able to find a solution. Most people there seem to be Linux users, so I thought that I might have better luck here, since this is definitely a Windows 7 issue.

**My setup**: Windows 7 x64, rclone v1.51, WinFsp 2020 v1.6.20027, 900/100Mbps internet.

**The issue**: When I mount a cloud drive (via the `rclone mount` command in the command prompt, started as a user without admin privileges), I can navigate the drive, stream videos, **rename and move folders** without any problems in Windows Explorer, but **when I as much as right click on a file (or try to move/rename it) the window becomes unresponsive** for minutes and I have to force stop it. Rclone mount keeps running in the command prompt and I can open another Window Explorer window for the mounted drive afterwards.

**I tried the following**:

- changing folder view
- disabling thumbnails
- reinstalling WinFsp
- rclone beta
- disabling preview pane
- disabling Windows Search
- disabling Windows Firewall
- disabling anti-malware software (Microsoft Security Essentials)
- sfc/scannow (no errors except TS_BrokenShortcuts.ps1 and TS_UnusedDesktopIcons.ps1, which I modified 
  myself; I replaced them with the original files)
- changing some network adapter settings (ecn, congestion provider, rss)
- ccleaner (except registry)
- Superfech is off
- Indexing is off
- Remote Differential Compression is off

**Additional info**:

- As I mentioned, this only affects files, not folders. All operations on folders are reasonably fast.
- The issue gets considerably better with FileZilla Pro, but some unresponsiveness still happens. I tried other Windows Explorer replacements, but with the exception of FileZilla and fman, it's pretty much the same as with Windows Explorer.
- I tested this on a device with Windows 10 and the problem doesn't occur there. I can rename/move files and the changes are pretty much instant.
- When I select a file in a mounted cloud drive, Windows Explorer shows a (green) progress bar in the address bar; it seems to be doing something with the file even upon selecting, but Idon't know what. This does not happen with folders.

**What could be causing the problem?**